# What is the best way to index data on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have 4 tables:

1. country
2. state
3. city
4. address

These tables are related by ids where country is the top parent:

- state.countryId
- city.stateId
- address.cityId

I want to integrate elastic search on my application and want to know what is the best way to index these table?

Should i create 1 index for each tables so that i have 1 index for each of country, state, city and address?

Or should i denormalize the tables and create only 1 index and store all the data with redundancy?

Answer (score 2):

ES is not afraid of redundancy in your data, so I would clearly denormalize so that each document represents one address like this:

```
{
    "country_id": 1,
    "country_name": "United Stated of America",
    "state_id": 1,
    "state_name": "California"
    "state_code": "CA",
    "city_id": 1,
    "city_name": "San Mateo"
    "zip_code": 94402,
    "address": "400 N El Camino Real"
}
```

You can then aggregate your data on whatever city, state, country field you wish.

Your mileage may vary as it ultimately depends on how you want to query/aggregate your data, but it's much easier to query address data like this in a single index instead of hitting several indices.

Comment: Right, i was going for something like this too, but was a bit hesitant to decide... i have one question though... what if you need the individual country or state or city records? do you store it like this? `{
    "country_id": 1,
    "country_name": "United States of America",
    "state_id": ,
    "state_name": 
    "state_code": ,
    "city_id": ,
    "city_name": 
    "zip_code": ,
    "address": 
}`

Comment: You could decide to only retrieve the `country_*` fields for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I like Val's answer, it is the most straight forward option. But if you really want to reduce duplication (for example to minimize size on disk) you could use [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) mapping. It will make indexing and querying a bit more verbose though. I still sugges to go with "flat" mapping.

You asked "what if you need the individual country or state or city records?", I'd recommend to add an additional field ([not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) or integer) which would indicate which level of hierarchy this document represents. It is fine not to have fields which correspond to lower levels of hierarchy. This way you could easily have a filter on just searching states or countries.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type) is a very useful article by @[adrien-grand](https://www.elastic.co/blog/author/adrien-grand) which elaborates on the subject of the trade-offs between creating many indexes, or less indexes and many types.

Hope it helps!