# how to avoid time out exception while indexing data in elasticsearch with concurrent requests?

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis, amazon-elasticsearch

we are indexing data in elasticsearch using java api and architecture is like there are multiple applications can be running at the same time so many concurrent requests may be made to ES due to which time out exception occures on elasticsearch.how to avoid this without autoscalling elasticsearch? 
We have found a approch to do it using kinesis firehose stream so the ES indexing request will go into Kinesis stream and then kinesis will forword it to ES.Is it the correct way to do it? Please suggest any another suitable approch .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to index data on elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160625/what-is-the-best-way-to-index-data-on-elasticsearch)

Comment: we have done indexing data to elastic search but my concern is how to do it  with concurrent request without having time out exception?